# LaTeX syntax for karp reduction

Tags: symbols

What is the LaTeX syntax for Karp reduction (i.e. the lesser than sign with curved lines instead of straight lines)?

Comment: Please see this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol and I think you're looking for `\succ` or `\prec` and their friends: `\succeq,\preceq`

Comment: @Seamus: Thanks. Could u post this as an answer so that this gets an answer?

Comment: Purely for making it easy for people to find that _canonical_ symbol-lookup question, I'm voting to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In future, there are a number of ways to [look up a symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol).

The "bendy inequality" symbols are:

`\succ`, `\prec`, `\succeq` and `\preceq`.

[image: bendy inequalities]

If you like the `eq` variants to bend too, then (with the help of the `amssymb` package you can:

```
$\succ \prec \succeq \preceq \succcurlyeq \preccurlyeq$
```

[image: more bendy inequalities]

Comment: Aesthetically, you may also prefer (as I do) the symbols `\succcurlyeq` and `\preccurlyeq` to their "non-curly" equivalents.

Comment: @Niels thanks for that! I couldn't remember what the command for them was.

Comment: Me neither, so I DeTeXified it. ;-)

Comment: @Seamus: Thanks. I have used DeTexify in the past but I completely forgot about it. DeTexify goes into my bookmark tab now.

Answer (score 0):

`\propto` is Karp Reduction in LaTeX.